# Second monitor randomly turns off and on

Tags: display, hardware, screen

I have an iMac running 10.9.2 and sporadically the second monitor turns off then on. It's only off for a second or two. It's an Acer AL2216W. It's connected from display port to DVI.

Comment: Is it possible that the monitor is broken?

Comment: I also think it's a problem with the monitor, it happens with my LG every once in a while and I think it's related to variations in the electricity.